# Error "Cannot find module 'npmlog'" after "npm update -g"

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I have NVM 0.30.1 and used it to install node.js v5.4.0 (with NPM 3.5.4) on Fedora 22. When I run `npm update -g`, I receive the following warnings:

```
npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled npm > init-package-json with new installed version
npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled npm > node-gyp with new installed version
npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled npm > npm-install-checks with new installed version
npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled npm > npmlog with new installed version
npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled npm > read-package-json with new installed version
```

And after that, when I run npm I get this error:

```
module.js:328
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at /home/peflorencio/.nvm/versions/node/v5.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:20:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/peflorencio/.nvm/versions/node/v5.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:76:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
```

Does anyone know what it is and how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. It was a [bug](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11134) and it has already been fixed in Node v5.4.1. Now it's working as usual.

Comment: I have Node 5.4.1 and after `npm update -g` it fails, too.

Answer (score 7):

What fixed this for me was

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

and then re-installing node (with npm).

Comment: This doesn't work... How do you install things using npm if you just blatted it?

`#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
sudo: npm: command not found
Exited with code 1`

Comment: @antony Re-install node itself! IIRC, I did this via the installer downloadable from the official node website

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `npm update -g` cannot update npm to the newest version. I solve the problem by updating npm installation manually.

1. Install/ reinstall node to get the bundled npm
2. run `npm install -g npm@3.5.4` to update the global npm installation
3. now `npm update -g` should work

Comment: please try "curl -0 -L http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh" for the 2nd step to see if it helps.

Comment: working for root : # npm -v
3.10.10
but not for jenkins user : jenkins@ip-172-31-22-20:~$ npm -v
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/local/bin/npm:19:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/bin/npm:75:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)

Comment: jenkins@ip-172-31-22-20:~$ node -v
v6.11.1

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issue in my Windows 10 PC. After looking into solutions, since i couldn't find the exact solution for the issue i was facing
**Cannot find module 'npmlog'**
I just uninstalled the node js and then, deleted both 'npm' and 'npm-cache' in 
"C:\Users\YourPCName\AppData\Roaming"

Then, i downloaded the latest version of node from [Node JS Website](https://nodejs.org/en/)

And, installed node js

After that i checked with the path in environment variables.

Finally run the command prompt 'run as administrator' and **npm install npm -g**

Checking your version will show the latest version. 'npm -v'

I got the latest version - v3.10.9

Try this. this should work.

Answer (score 2):

If people with linux are facing the problem, here is the solution:

As of the date of this post, the NPM version packaged with Nodejs doesn't work. If you installed this package, run

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm
sudo apt-get install node
sudo mv /usr/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/npm
```

New version should be 3.10.8 and the old error gone

Answer (score 1):

init-package-json, node-gyp, npm-install-checks, npmlog, read-package-json didn't installed correctly. Not sure why though.

Didn't find the root cause for the issue but I used the hacky way to install the packages above for now:

- Roll back to the previous node version which npm didn't be updated. For example, `nvm use iojs`
- `cd` to where npm installed, for example, `cd /home/peflorencio/.nvm/versions/node/v5.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm` and reinstall those packages like `rm -rf node_modules/init-package-json && npm install init-package-json` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers already answered the question, but I will still like to throw in my own idea. I encountered same issue after I was told to run `npm update -g npm` after running that piece of code, the error started. I solved mine by using Node Version Manager(`nvm`):

```
nvm install 8
```

**Note:** not actually 8, but to a version of your choice e.g(6,5). Writing the version number will automatically install the stable of the version specified.
After the installation you should get a CLI message:

```
Now using node v8.11.4 (npm v5.6.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac, perform the following steps, to remedy (assuming you have Homebrew installed already):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/npm*
```

(to overcome `bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory` error):

```
hash -r
```

Then go ahead with updating brew (to keep its kegs up to date) and the reinstallation process, linking is optional.

```
brew update

brew reinstall node

brew link --overwrite node
```

At any point inbetween you can use `npm -v` or `node -v` to test whether or not you are making progress. If you have `node` returning a version, but not `npm` then you will need to add your path to your environment with:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Don't forget to run `npm rebuild` inside of your projects, after this sort of upgrade takes place, as it will update the C++ binaries

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to bump npm without reinstalling node.

```
#### # this will remove current npm
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/

#### # install npm from sources. Version 3.5.x will be installed
apt-get update
apt-get install npm

#### # install the newest npm version. Bumping from 3.5.X to 6.14.X goes without any issue :)
/usr/bin/npm install npm@latest -g

#### # additionally, npm with version 3.5.x is not added to $PATH, so it's not used.
```