# npmlog error on windows 7

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I am stuck with npm commands. I am using webstorm and when I run any command like npm install I a getting an error. I have tried researching on what can be done but nothing I have tried so far seems to work. should I create a file called npmlog. if so what should its extension be and what should be the path.

```
C:\workspace\Main_Dev>npm install
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:18:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:75:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
```

please help me. thanks.

Comment: For similar a question, check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702617/error-cannot-find-module-npmlog-after-npm-update-g

Comment: I checked that one, it looks like uninstalling and reinstalling was suggested or rolling back to previous version. this is my only install and i cant get the older version . at my work i dont think i can ask for that.