# npm Error “ Cannot find module 'npmlog' ”

Tags: node.js, npm, centos, npm-install

I am running CentOS 6 and after logging in, I encounter the following error

```
  module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /home/dspace/.nvm/v0.10.31/bin/npm:19:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dspace/.nvm/v0.10.31/bin/npm:87:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v0.10.31 --silent` to unset it.
```

I've discovered that it is a version bug and can be resolved either by upgrading the npm version or by deleting the node modules like so;

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Then reinstalling them;

```
npm install
```

After removing the modules, npm install failed to run because of missing dependancies i.e. the modules. Now the command shows no response at all.

My node version is v0.10.48

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "Cannot find module 'npmlog'" after "npm update -g"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702617/error-cannot-find-module-npmlog-after-npm-update-g)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

1. Install nvm:
   `wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash`
2. Restart the terminal
3. Run
   `nvm install node`

Comment: worked for me on macOS

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after proposed npm upgrade via `npm -i -g npm`. But Fedora npm/node installed via `dnf` has modules links to `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/` from `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/`. I saw links were broken because `usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/` disappeared. So reinstallation `node,nodejs,npm` via `dnf/rpm` solved the problem.