# BCRYPT - Build from source on Alpine:node and causes segfaults using this docker file when its used

Tags: node.js, docker, bcrypt, alpine-linux

Build this docker file and try and use Bcrypt to complete a hash and it will segfault, and I can't figure out why for the life of me.

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:9.1.0

MAINTAINER James Claridge  <james@claridgeand.co>

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python
RUN npm config set python /usr/bin/python
RUN npm i -g npm
RUN npm install
RUN npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source
RUN apk del builds-deps
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to install a npm version that has a bug. 
In your installation, `RUN npm install` doesn't work, so, `rebuild bcrypt` crashes.

After that, you should add before `npm install` some commands like explained in these links:

[error-cannot-find-module-npmlog-after-npm-update-g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702617/error-cannot-find-module-npmlog-after-npm-update-g)

[Issue npm version 5.4.1 solved upgrading to 6.1.0](https://github.com/tj/n/issues/101#issuecomment-15090791)

> **EDIT**: It's an issue related to alpine-node version available packages:

Use this Dockerfile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:latest 

MAINTAINER James Claridge  <james@claridgeand.co>

RUN apk update
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python
RUN npm config set python /usr/bin/python
RUN npm i -g npm
RUN npm install
RUN npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source
RUN apk del builds-deps
```

Comment: Still not working but I'm a step closer now - now its stuck on

api_1       | NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires
api_1       | NODE_MODULE_VERSION 59. Please try re-compiling or re-installing

despite having an uptodate npm version

Comment: I think I've found solution. If you change in your Dockerfile `alpine-node` version from 9.1.0 to 10.5.0 it works (latest): `FROM mhart/alpine-node:latest`, but adding `RUN apk update`. See latest version in https://hub.docker.com/r/mhart/alpine-node/

Comment: For `FROM node:16.13-alpine3.15`
run command should be like: `RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual .builds-deps build-base python3`

Answer (score 7):

Use `bcryptjs`, it doesn't require you to install additional dependencies and rebuild from source. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs

If you really want to use the `bcrypt`, see their [issue on github](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/528) and their [instructions](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions#alpine-linux-based-images). There are some workaround there, but this will require some additional dependency installing. The easiest way to keep using `bcrypt` would be to not use the alpine version, but the ubuntu version of node (with its additional overhead).